# selecting nested json with angular

Tags: json, angularjs

I have a select box that is populated with json. Here is the json...

```
{
"Connectivity": [

    {
        "product_id": 1,
        "product_name": "SmartLink",
        "product_price_attributes": [
            {
                "key": "postcodeA",
                "type": "text"
            },
            {
                "key": "BearerBW",
                "type": "text"

            },
            {
                "key": "Total bandwidth",
                "type": "text"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "product_id": 2,
        "product_name": "SmartNet",
        "product_price_attributes": [
            {
                "key": "postcodeA",
                "type": "text"
            },
            {
                "key": "BearerBW",
                "type": "text"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "product_id": 3,
        "product_name": "Centralised Internet",
        "product_price_attributes": [
            {
                "key": "BearerBW",
                "type": "text"
            }
        ]
    }

],
"Cloud Services": [
    {
        ...
    }
]
}
```

I use this code in the controller to populate the drop down

```
 $http.get('scripts/json/sample-products.json')
        .then(function(res){
            $scope.portfolio1 = res.data.Connectivity;
        });
```

This creates the select box like this

```
<select ng-model="selectedProduct" ng-options="opt as opt.product_name for opt in portfolio1" 
ng-change="getPriceAttributes()">
<option value="0" selected="selected" label="SmartLink">SmartLink</option>
<option value="1" label="SmartNet">SmartNet</option>
<option value="2" label="Centralised Internet">Centralised Internet</option>
```

When I pick an option from my select box getPriceAttributes() is fired. It looks like this...

```
 $scope.getPriceAttributes = function() {
        $http.get('scripts/json/sample-products.json')
            .then(function(res){
                $scope.formFields = res.data;
            });
    };
```

So my issue is that I don't know how I should drill down to get to the nested object 'product_price_attributes' for a selected product. I'm not sure what I need to pass to getPriceAttributes or what I need to change to the function to get it working.

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`selectedProduct` is set to be `opt` - which is each item in the `Connectivity` array, so simply:

```
console.log($scope.selectedProduct.product_price_attributes)
```

You can also pass in the model as a param to the `change` function:

```
$scope.getPriceAttributes = function(item) {
    console.log(item.product_price_attributes)
    ...
}

<select ng-model="selectedProduct" ng-options="opt as opt.product_name for opt in portfolio1" ng-change="getPriceAttributes(selectedProduct)">
```